# Rsync between directories with special characters

Tags: rsync

How can I use rsync to copy a list of files (`*.txt`) from one directory to another?

The directories contain spaces and special characters.

Example of files (full path):

```
/media/alarazr/External/Music/Will Varley/Will Varley - I Got This Email.mp3
/media/alarazr/External/Music/Will Varley/Will Varley - Weddings & Wars.mp3
/media/alarazr/External/Music/Windir/Windir - Destroy.mp3
/media/alarazr/External/Music/WWO/WWO - Afisz.mp3
/media/alarazr/External/Music/WWO/WWO - Damy Rade (Instrumental).mp3
```

And destination directory:

```
/media/alarazr/External/Music2/[[sort
```

Answer (score 1):

Those file names don't look like they contain specials, just whitespace. So a normal application of `rsync` should be fine. Assuming `list.txt`, this command will copy all the files into the specified directory:

```
rsync -avP --files-from=list.txt '/media/alarazr/External/Music2/[[sort/'
```

Remove the `-P` flag if you're running this from a non-interactive session

Answer (score 0):

well, I figured it out:

```
rsync -av --files-from=/path/to/files.txt / /destination/path/
```